# Simple XML PHP error - Echo's nothing

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Ok guys,

Essentially, im loading a simplexml_load_file from a URL like this

```
$stats =  simplexml_load_file("http://example.com/api/api.asmx/Campaign.GetSummary?ApiKey=$apikey&CampaignID=$CID");
```

Which returns this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Recipients] => 1
    [TotalOpened] => 0
    [Clicks] => 0
    [Unsubscribed] => 0
    [Bounced] => 0
    [UniqueOpened] => 0
)
```

After I load that up I want to echo the info, so I try to echo it out like so

```
echo '<ul id="views">'; 
echo '<li>';
print $stats['Recipients'];
echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

But when it runs, I dont get any of the data, just an empty `<li></li>`

Comment: Have you tried $stats->Recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with SimpleXMLElements, you do not use the `[]` notation - instead you use `->`. So, your code should be:

```
echo '<ul id="views">'; 
echo '<li>';
print $stats->Recipients;
echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

I believe such notation *may* (it does in my application, but I am not overly familiar with SimpleXMLElements) return a SimpleXMLElement object, not a string - you can cast it to a string/int/whatever to use it in comparisons etc.

Comment: Thanks, cant believe that slipped my mind. Really appreciate it sir.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleXMLElement Object` is not an array, it is an Object, the clue is in the name :-)

You need to access it using Object notation

```
 $stats->Recipients
```